# What tool can I use to decompile an executable written in VB.net and create a project?

Tags: vb.net, decompiling

What tool can I use to decompile an executable written in VB.net and create a project? I need to debug and fix an application, but the code is lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of decompilers around.  Just use them all, the compiler will tell you which one works best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several decompilers on the market, my personal choice is Telerik's JustDecompile, it's free and let you create a project from a .NET assembly, however, note that if the .NET assembly is obfuscated, the decompiler output may be useless, and you may need to use a deobfuscator first (or later).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but the resulting project cannot be compiled. I get many errors. How can that be explained? e.g. 'My' is not a member of 'theProject.theProject'.

Comment: There may be many reasons why the resulting code is uncompilable, one being that it may be obfuscated, other it may be that does things that JustDecompile simply can't translate; what's important is that you know that the decompiled code is a representation of the code as the decompiler understands it, not as it was written. Using a different decompiler, may give you different results, and for the problems you find you may better look them up individually.